# Navigating programmatically in swift(IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mobile, segue

I am just picking up iOS development as an Android developer. In Android it is possible to set clicklistener on any view which I find difficult in iOS except with Gesture Recognizer. I want to  set the gesture recognizer on a view to navigate from one view controller to another. Can I be guided

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        initiateTapGestures(view: circleView, action: #selector(self.tapDetectedForProfile))
    }


    func initiateTapGestures(view:UIView, action:Selector?){
        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: action)
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
     }
    @objc func tapDetectedForProfile(){
        print("profile setting")
        let profile = ProfileViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ProfileViewController(), animated: false)

    }
```

Comment: We have UIButton for that purpose... don't add tapGesture which is wrong way of doing in iPhone.

Comment: do you have a navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   circle.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didClickedView(_ :))))
}  

@objc func didClickedView(_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("profile setting")
        let profile = ProfileViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ProfileViewController(), animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works buh just like I did previously, the destination(ProfileViewController) is showing a black page.

Comment: set background color to ProfileViewController  `view.backgroundColor = .red` on viewDidLoad()

Comment: The ProfileViewController is built on storyboard already. I have views in it

Comment: most of time this happen when you didn't set background colour to viewController, Sometimes it can be constraints problem.Can you add screenshot of your storyboard showing constraints

Comment: have been able to solve is with ```let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardID") as! viewController```

Comment: One more thing, how can transfer object(parse object) while navigating thereby transferring the object to the destination.

Answer (score 1):

You create an object and push another one here

```
    let profile = ProfileViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ProfileViewController(), animated: false)

}
```

Comment: I am getting the error reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapDetectedForProfile))
    //tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2 //Default is 1 no need to mention  //2 Double tab //3...
    //tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2 // Default is 1. The number of fingers required to match
    circleView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

@objc func tapDetectedForProfile() {
    print("Tabbed")
    // do something
    // Navigation
}
```